# Thread lock needed for different object in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, thread-safety

Given 4 threads and a list storing 2 objects (image frames) `l[o1,o2]` (i guess references to the objects, therefore my question), .

threads 1 & 2 read/write `o1`.

threads 3 & 4 of them read/write `o2`.

Is the same lock needed for all 4 threads or can they use two different locks (one for threads 1 & 2 and one for threads 3 & 4) ? Locks acquired with

`lock1 = threading.Lock(); lock2 = threading.Lock()`

Naively, from what i read, a single lock should be used. On the other hand, not sure the list in this use case is not thread-safe ???

Comment: All common Python implementations have a GIL or per-object locks. Primitive operations on builtin types are thread safe.

Comment: beyond GIL, writing object o1 in the array is atomic, it is just a reference update for the object location ?